# Find item in array of structure

Tags: arrays, vb.net, search, structure

I have a question. Imagine that in vb.net, fill a array of structure with a lot of items. For example, here I declare the structure called Persons:

```
    Public structure Persons
         Dim name as string
         Dim age as integer
    End structure
```

Then, I declare a variable that is a array of persons, for make a list of friends, like this:

```
    Dim friends() as Persons
    friends(0).name = "Sebastian"
    friends(0).age = 19

    friends(1).name = "Michael"
    friends(1).age = 34

    ...
```

So, there are any form to locate where is the position of "Sebastian"?? In other words. If I would know if "Sebastian" exist in any friends(i).name, and, if exist, returns me the position (i), how I can do this??

Thanks

Comment: Why array and not `List(Of Persons)`? Is this homework? Btw, you should to name the struct `Person` (singular) , not `Persons` (plural).

Comment: ...and why not a Person Class rather than a struct?

Comment: Hi Bjorn. Homework? You must be kidding. The answer why not List(of Persons) is because I think that is more clean be this like a structure, not how a list. Maybe I'm wrong, I don't know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer = Array.FindIndex(friends, Function(f) f.name = "Michael")
```

The variable i should have the position of the person named "Michael".

Comment: just keep in mind this will return the index of the first "Michael". This is probably exactly what you want but consider what if there are multiple "Michael"s.

Comment: I will try this. Well, the information of the question is a example. In the project will don't exist repeated names :)

Comment: Hey @Diego! The solution works perfectly, it returns me the position of the item that I want.

Thank you very much :)