# How to find the string inside the Array of Structure?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to find the same exact value of the string in the Array of Structure.

SAMPLE String: `Dim xEntity_Handle As String = "PX101" 'SAMPLE DATA Retrieved`

I have a `Structure` Like this:

```
   Public Structure Member
        Public strHandle As String
        Public materialType As String
    End Structure
```

And I have created a list like this:

```
Dim Ary_memberList as New List(Of Member)
```

Now, This is the problem, I don't want to use a Loop for comparing each value of the `Member.strHandle` to the string I had mentioned above.

I did try something like this `Array.FindIndex, Array.Find` to solve the problem but It does not work on my case. Also, I found this solution at this site, but it doesn't work for me.

[Find item in array of structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998204/find-item-in-array-of-structure)

Comment: If it didn't work in your case then you probably did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, we can't see what's wrong with it. ALWAYS show us what you did. That's how this site works.

Comment: Maybe: `Dim h = Ary_memberList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.strHandle.IndexOf(xEntity_Handle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`

Comment: @JQSOFT It doesnt seem to be right sir because `FirstOrDefault` is not a member of the collection. And Also Sir, I am not using a Lambda Expression For this. Can you make it broad??

Comment: You need to `Import System.Linq` namespace buddy.

Comment: Also this `Dim h = Array.Find(Ary_memberList.ToArray, Function(x) x.strHandle.IndexOf(xEntity_Handle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)` will do.

Comment: @JQSOFT , Thank you sir. Please Move it to the Answer and I will accept it. It work but there is not value, I think the problem is on my condition. Thank you sir.

Comment: Welcome mate. Make sure that the fields have their values assigned before you execute one of the mentioned above lines. Good luck.